# Delete attribute from model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I generated a User model using this command:

```
rails generate model User name:string date_birth:date age:int...
```

As you can see I made a mistake. I entered a date of birth and an age. Now I also migrated into a mySql database. Is there any way to just delete the age field?

Edit: Is it also possible to add a field?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create a new migration with

```
rails g migration migrationname
```

and in the migration's up method run
the following

```
remove_column :users, :age
```

run rake db:migrate and you are good to go.

Comment: Yep.  add_column :tablename, :fieldname, :fieldtype

Answer (score 2):

At least two choices:

1. You can run `rake db:rollback`, delete the field from the migration and then re-run `rake db:migrate`
2. You can create a new migration to delete the field with `rails generate migration new_migration`.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following in terminal

rails destroy model User

This should reverse the generate so you can start again

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit your migration file and remove the column which you don't need from the migration file, and then `rake db:migrate` again.